# httrack fails to download website due to anti-crawler protection

Tags: httrack

I'm trying to clone this entire website for someone who lost access to their hosting login (for reasons I won't get into) and needs a local copy of everything:
https://www.cowpatch.com/

It looks like it is created with wordpress.

I'm using httrack from terminal on a mac. Here's the command I'm running:

```
httrack https://www.cowpatch.com/  -O "/Users/abe/websites/cowpatch"
```

It gets index.html, but there seems to be some kind of anti-crawler mechanism stopping it from getting the other pages on the site. All the other HTML pages downloaded display a message saying the following:

> Anti-Crawler Protection is checking your browser and IP … for spam
> bots. You will be automatically redirected to the requested page after
> 3 seconds. Don't close this page. Please, wait for 3 seconds to pass
> to the page. Anti-Spam by CleanTalk

My take on this is that because httrack doesn't wait the three seconds, it ends up cloning this anti-crawler redirection page rather than crawling to the correct URL.

Is there a workaround? Some option I can use to fix this? I've been looking through the httrack user guide, but no luck so far.

Comment: option ` #u  Wait time`  "On hold" option, in seconds?

Comment: I think that's the [Spam protection, AntiSpam, FireWall by CleanTalk](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cleantalk-spam-protect/) wordpress plugin. They can simply contact their hosting provider and provide proof of their identity and the hosting provider will be happy to send their credentials to them. The reason you gave for crawling the website does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: `wget` with `--wait=seconds` option?

Comment: Did they lose not only their wordpress login, but also the access to the files and the database so they can't disable the plugin in all 3 places?